# LlinkedIn not able to Logout in WebView

Tags: android, webview, linkedin-api

I am loading one URL in WebView , in that have LinkedIn Sign In ,after logged in to it, am not able to logout. I have cleared cookies by two ways below, still not solved issue. Please help...

**Way 1:**

```
LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).clearSession();
```

**Way 2:**

```
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "bcookie=");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "bscookie=");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "visit=");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "sl=");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "lang=1");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "JSESSIONID=");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "li_at=");
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(".linkedin.com", "bcookie=");
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time I need to do anything else than displaying a simple HTML page in a Webview, I get nuts. They've changed/broken several things for each Android version, so you have to duplicate each single line of code.

Once I had to clear the cookies of a webview in my app and I did it using `cookieManager.removeAllCookie()`, which was deprecated after Lollipop.

Also I used `webview.clearCache()`. According to the documentation: *Clears the resource cache. Note that the cache is per-application, so this will clear the cache for all WebViews used.* Thus, you don't need to actually refer to your current webview (quite useful if this log out is handled in a separate place of the app).

So I combined these 2 solutions by doing:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.removeAllCookies(new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(Boolean value) {
                //Removed?
           }
        });
        cookieManager.flush();
    } else {
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
    }

    new WebView(getApplicationContext()).clearCache(true);
```

This solved my problem of logging out from a different website than LinkedIn. I don't know if there is any other special trick you would need to accomplish for your particular case.

Comment: If you said that "removing all cookies ", all cookies of Linked in as well as given url cookies  removed . But here given url cookies need to be exists. So I want to clear linked in cookies only ... I think now you got my problem.....

Comment: If you need to preserve some cookies, then my solution won't work for you. Sorry, I didn't know this restriction when I replied you.